# Using <a> tag with ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code and it's working but i want to use `( <a> )` tag instead of `( <input type='submit'> )`. I am a beginner in php - I hope my question will be entertained. I have googled my problem but it didn't help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function load(thediv, thefile)
        {
            //alert('works');
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {

                xmlhttp = new  XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(!(xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200))
            {
                    // alert('works');
                    document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

            }
            xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile, false );
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type='submit' value="submit" onclick='load('main','itc_result.php');'>
</body>
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to use an `<a>` instead of a submit button? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You can do it like`<a onclick="load('main','itc_result.php');">Click Me </a>`.But what it's need is not clear?

Comment: `i have following code and its working` - I doubt that code does anything but log errors to the console

Comment: anchor tag looks better that "input type ='submit ' "  thats wht i want to use anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:-

`<a onclick="load('main','itc_result.php');">Click Me </a>.`

But what it's need is not clear?Submit works fine.

Comment: Anchr tag given by you is working , but there is still a problem,
when i click the anchor tag it shows the required page data but suddenly disapears ..!

Answer (score 0):

```html
favorite
i have following code and its working but i want to use ( <a> ) tage instead of "( <input type='submit'> ) " i am a beginner in php, hope my question will be entertained, i have goggled my problem but it didn't help me

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function load(thediv, thefile)
        {
            //alert('works');
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {

                xmlhttp = new  XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(!(xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200))
            {
                    // alert('works');
                    document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

            }
   alert('sending ajax');
            xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile, false );
            xmlhttp.send();
          
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" />
    <a href="#" onclick="load('main','itc_result.php');" >submit</a>
</body>
```

add the above into onclick of anchor tag like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="load('main','itc_result.php');" >submit</a>
```

Comment: really? not `onclick="load('main','itc_result.php');"` or onclick='load("main","itc_result.php");'` ?? both far more readable

Comment: and how to handle <a> tag with ajax ?

Comment: onclick of a tag you will call load method

Comment: create a div element with main id to see output

Comment: why? `i have following code and its working`